# Error Message: "no match for 'operator+='" after using "string* +="

Tags: c++, string, pointers

i have a problem with c++. I used a string pointer and wanted to add a other string dynamically. 
But then i've got this errormessage:

> no match for 'operator+=' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::string* {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string*}' and 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string}')

```
void Stammbaum::printTree(Node* node, string* s){
    printLeftTree(node, s, 0);
}

void Stammbaum::printLeftTree(Node* node, string* s, int i){
    if(node == NULL)
        return;

    if(i != 0)
        printLeftTree(node->Mutter, s, 1);

    string temporaryString;
    temporaryString = "/-- " + node->vorname + " " + node->nachname + "\n";
    s += temporaryString;                     <------------------------------Getting the error in this Line--

    printLeftTree(node->Vater, s, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`s` is a string pointer so it should be this

```
*s += temporaryString;
```

If I understand what you are trying to do here, then normally in C++ you would use a reference not a pointer, then you wouldn't need `*`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `s` is a *pointer* to a `std::string` object, attempting to add to it will add to the pointer itself not the object it points to.

You need to dereference the pointer to get the `std::string` object:

```
*s += temporaryString;
```

A much better solution (IMO) is to use *references* instead of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `std::string` member function `append`, appends string at end;

```
s->append( temporaryString );
```

like others suggested, use reference instead of pointers